# TradingView Alerrt Message Question - (alertcondition custom message question)

Tags: pine-script

I am hoping someone help me.I know this is probably really simple, but I couldn't figure it out.

In a pivots script , it has the user can input the pivot type:

`pivotType = input(title="Pivot Type", options=["Daily", "Intraday", "Weekly"], defval="Daily")`

In the alert message, I want it to state the pivot type hit when the alert goes off.  I want the message to say "Daily Pivot level hit", or "Weekly Pivot level hit".  I tried the following below, but it didn't appear to work.:

`alertcondition(condition=cross(close, r1), title="All Pivots Alert", message="A {{pivotType}} Pivot level hit")`

I tried the format above, but it didn't appear to work.  What do I need code in to have the pivotType be displayed as part of the message?

Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to include dynamic text in `alertcondition()` message text. See [Is it possible to use a string that varies as an argument to the alertcondition() function’s message= parameter?](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#is-it-possible-to-use-a-string-that-varies-as-an-argument-to-the-alertcondition-functions-message-parameter) for more details.

You could use this technique to plot a varying numeric value corresponding to each of your conditions: [How can I include values that change in my alerts?](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-include-values-that-change-in-my-alerts)