# Can't add values to string - pine script

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to add some values to my message strings but I get an Error on line 23 (buyMessage line) by using the tostring method. Can someone help me?

Error:

`Cannot call 'alertcondition' with arguments (series[bool], title=literal string, message=series[string]); available overloads: alertcondition(series[bool], const string, const string, string) => void; alertcondition(<arg_condition_type>, const string, const string, string) => void`

Code:

```
study("study1")

// Indicators
ema200 = ema(close, 200)
atr = atr(14)

// Plot
plot(atr, title='atr', color=color.red)

leverage = round(1 / (atr / close * 100 * 2))
amount = (leverage * 100) - 100


buyMessage  = 'binanceFutures(BTCUSD) { exchangeSettings(leverage=' + tostring(leverage) + '); aggressive(side=buy, amount=' + tostring(amount) + '); stopOrTakeProfit(side=sell, amount=' + tostring(amount) +', tp=' + tostring(atr * 2) + ', sl=' + tostring(atr) +');}'
sellMessage = 'binanceFutures(BTCUSD) { exchangeSettings(leverage=' + tostring(leverage) + '); aggressive(side=sell, amount=' + tostring(amount) + '); stopOrTakeProfit(side=buy, amount=' + tostring(amount) +', tp=' + tostring(atr * 2) + ', sl=' + tostring(atr) +');}'

// Alerts
alertcondition(close > ema200, title='Buy', message=buyMessage)
alertcondition(close < ema200, title='Sell', message=sellMessage)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... It actually is possible to use your own variables dynamically, apart from the standard variables, like {{ticker}} {{close}} {{open}} etc.
With a small workaround :)

You need to plot your value and use that in your alertcondition: {{plot_xx}}
The trick is to plot the value without trashing your scale. By doing so:

```
plotchar((isOk)?1234:na, "entry multiplier", "", location.top)
```

After that you can reference it by the plot number and it works :)

Edit: 5 februari 2021
It is even possible to use alerts now with a dynamic text! For more details check this blogpost, it will probably solve all alerting issues :)
https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/our-new-alerts-allow-for-dynamic-messages-22588/

Answer (score 0):

The `message` argument needs to be a constant (fixed text).
You can read about that in the description of the [alertcontidion()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_alertcondition) function.

Your message strings are not constant.
They're a `series` because they contain the variable `leverage`, which is a mutable variable.

It will compile when you use fixed text, like this:

```
//@version=4
study("study1")

// Indicators
ema200 = ema(close, 200)
atr = atr(14)

// Plot
plot(atr, title='atr', color=color.red)

leverage = round(1 / (atr / close * 100 * 2))
amount = (leverage * 100) - 100


// buyMessage  = 'binanceFutures(BTCUSD) { exchangeSettings(leverage=' + tostring(leverage) + '); aggressive(side=buy, amount=' + tostring(amount) + '); stopOrTakeProfit(side=sell, amount=' + tostring(amount) +', tp=' + tostring(atr * 2) + ', sl=' + tostring(atr) +');}'
// sellMessage = 'binanceFutures(BTCUSD) { exchangeSettings(leverage=' + tostring(leverage) + '); aggressive(side=sell, amount=' + tostring(amount) + '); stopOrTakeProfit(side=buy, amount=' + tostring(amount) +', tp=' + tostring(atr * 2) + ', sl=' + tostring(atr) +');}'

buyMessage  = "buyMessage Fixed Text"
sellMessage = "sellMessage Fixed Text"

// Alerts
alertcondition(close > ema200, title='Buy', message=buyMessage)
alertcondition(close < ema200, title='Sell', message=sellMessage)
```

Comment: Okay thanks and there isn't another way to send variabel messages through 'alertcondition'?

Comment: You can only use the [predefined variables](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/introducing-variables-in-alerts-14880/) in alerts. Custom variables are not possible.

Comment: However, there might be a solution, but only for numeric values. See the links in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62938813/tradingview-alerrt-message-question-alertcondition-custom-message-question). Especially the 2nd link.